# Create a new column by grouping on type, new column's value is entire group's column value

Tags: string, python-2.7, pandas, group-by, aggregate

I have a pandas dataframe that essentially looks like this:

```
type    item    string
1       0       aa
1       1       bb
1       2       cc

2       0       dd
2       1       ee
2       2       ff
```

I want to somehow create a new column 'newstring' based off of the group's 'string' column

```
type    item    string  newstring
1       0       aa      aa+bb+cc
1       1       bb      aa+bb+cc
1       2       cc      aa+bb+cc

2       0       dd      dd+ee+ff
2       1       ee      dd+ee+ff
2       2       ff      dd+ee+ff
```

I've done

```
df.groupby('type').aggregate(lambda x: "+".join(x))
df.groupby('type').apply(lambda x: "+".join(x))
```

but I keep getting as a result in newstring (literally)

```
type    item    string  newstring
1       0       aa      type+item+string+newstring
1       1       bb      type+item+string+newstring
1       2       cc      type+item+string+newstring

2       0       dd      type+item+string+newstring
2       1       ee      type+item+string+newstring
2       2       ff      type+item+string+newstring
```

How can I group by a specific column but then append the values of one column of that group to a new column.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry are you after this:

```
In [14]:
df['new_string'] = df.groupby('type')['string'].transform(lambda x: '+'.join(x))
df

Out[14]:

   type  item string new_string
0     1     0     aa   aa+bb+cc
1     1     1     bb   aa+bb+cc
2     1     2     cc   aa+bb+cc
3     2     0     dd   dd+ee+ff
4     2     1     ee   dd+ee+ff
5     2     2     ff   dd+ee+ff
```

The above groups on 'type' and then we call `transform` on 'string' column and call a lambda function that `join`'s the string values.

The reason what you tried failed was because your function is being applied on the remaining columns rather than specifically for the string column. Also the `transform` here returns a series with an index aligned with the original df.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Fairly obvious now that I see it. Thank you so much!